# JDBC with VSCode class not found

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, visual-studio-code, connection

I am having serious trouble creating a Java Project with VS Code with adding the "mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar".
I have done the following steps:

- Creating a fresh Java project with VS Code from the command line
- Adding the mysql connector by doing "Add referenced libraries".

I tried using both jdk 11 and 15 (not 8 since VS Code doesn't support it anymore)

Launching my code result in the error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.LocalizedErrorMessages`

Here is an extract of my code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SimpleJDBCApplication {

   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company";
   static final String DB_DRV = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
   static final String DB_USER = "root";
   static final String DB_PASSWD = "";

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException,
         IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {

      Connection connection = null;
      Statement statement = null;
      ResultSet resultSet = null;

      try{
          /*To connect with a database using JDBC you need to select get the
                 driver for the respective database and register the driver.
                 The forName() method of the class named Class accepts a class name
                as a String parameter and loads it into the memory, Soon the is
                loaded into the memory it gets registered automatically  */  
                //Take new instance
         System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
         connection=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,DB_USER,DB_PASSWD);
         statement=connection.createStatement();
         resultSet=statement.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM dept");
         while(resultSet.next()){
            System.out.printf("%d\t%s\t%s\n",
            resultSet.getInt(1),
            resultSet.getString(2),
            resultSet.getString(3));
```

The error occures at the line `connection=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,DB_USER,DB_PASSWD);`

Thank you for any help

[Library added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56auj.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH51H.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.This is applicable to MySQL version below 8.0:

> static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company";

Change it to

```
static final String DB_URL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC"
```

2.Transfer `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`;

3.`Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")` is enough, also with this code,  `System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` isn't needed, you can comment or delete it;

This works for me and you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager) the class name should be `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. Also the call to `getDeclaredConstructor()` seems to be unnecessary. Maybe those are the source of your problems.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately, I tried both of your solutions (replacing com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver and removing getDeclaredConstructor()) but none of them works :( I still get the exact same error

Comment: @SoaAlex I'm facing the same error even after adding the ref-lib, can you tell if your prob was solved? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Click on Java Projects in the explorer tab on the left-hand side in VSCode. Then right-click on your project name and click on Configure Classpath. this will open Classpath Configuration in a new tab. Scroll to the bottom and then click add on the referenced libraries. This will open an explorer pop-up window. Select the java-mysql connector jar file and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Open java projects from bottom left of VS Code

Step 2) Click on + button on refrenced libraries

Step 3) Browse for the driver i.e. the connector file in this case.

Step 4) Problem solved & connection created